# exponential functions and calculus

Tags: calculus

Assume the rate of change of a quantity T is proportional to the difference between the quantity T and some fixed constant A. 
That is 
dT/dt = K(T-A)
show that T=A+Ce^(kt) (where C is a constant) is a solution to this differential equation.
I dont really know what the question is asking me to even try and begin to attempt it, if anyone can help me out that would be great thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are given $T=A+Ce^{kt}$ as a possible solution for the differential equation.  Take $\frac {dT}{dt}$ and plug it into the equation.  See that it is satisfied once you make the two $K$'s the same.

Comment: Coukd you elaborate on what you mean by that? how would I sub in dT/dt into the equation im assuming T=A+Ce^(kt) ?

Comment: Take the derivative of $A+Ce^{Kt}$ with respect to $t$, assuming that $A$ and $C$ are constants. This is the $LHS$ of the equation. Now evaluate $RHS=K(T-A)=K((A+Ce^{Kt})-A)$. If $LHS=RHS$, then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $\frac{dT}{dt}=K(T-A)$ as follows:

$$\frac{dT}{(T-A)}=K dt$$

Or equivalently,

$$d(\ln (T-A))=K dt$$

Now, integrate both sides to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method of first order linear differential equations:

$$\frac{dT}{dt}+p(t)T=q(t)$$

$$T(t)=\frac{\int u(t)q(t)dt+C}{u(t)}$$

where

$$u(t)=e^{\int p(t)dt}$$